# flow-type annotations for lodash find()

Tags: javascript, lodash, flowtype, flow-typed

In a javascript function I'm using lodash _.find() to select an item from an array. I've installed the lodash definition from flow-typed and it is working and available.

The only way I have figured out how to use the _.find() method with annotations is by type-casting it after not adding types to the const where I perform the find:

```
import { find } from 'lodash';

...

const items: Array<Item> = user.items;
const item = find(items, {"id", selectedId});

let finalItem: Item = ((item: any): Item);
...
```

**I'm not getting any errors** however, I can't tell if I've properly done this properly or if I've merely short-circuited the type-safety by casting it to an 'any' first and gained myself nothing. Is there a "more proper" way of annotating/using Lodash methods and flow-type together?

Also, if I am doing it correctly, is there a syntax available for doing the casting on one line, something along the lines of:

```
const item: ((item: any): Item) = find(items, {"id": selectedId });
```

but correct.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Shouldn't it be `Item|void` since it might not find anything?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors the way it is currently written. Good tip on the void type. In this case there will always be a result Item (famous last words) b/c the code will return the Item marked as default if no matching ID is found (and no set of items can exist w/o one being default). I left that out since it felt non-pertinent to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting from `_.find` is typed as `Item|void`. When using the result of `_.find` you should handle all the cases: `null`, `undefined` or `Item`.

What you can do to make sure you are dealing with something of type `Item` in the rest of the code is to fail in any other cases.

```
const items: Array<Item> = user.items;
const item = find(items, {"id", selectedId});
if (item === null || item === undefined) {
  throw new Error(`Could not find item with id ${selectedId} in items`}
}

// In lines below item is type of Item
...
```

This will throw an error if the `id` cannot be found in the `items` array. You may want to deal with `null` and `undefined` results in a different way to avoid stopping you program in this situation.

Force casting the result of `_.find` to be an `Item` is probably not the solution you want to implement because `null` or `undefined` will be typed as `Item` which will throw a runtime error when using `item` value.